# unidimensional battleship game in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm a college student and a beginner Java developer. I got this assignment for which I need to simulate a unidimensional battleship game using strings. The rules given to me are as follows:

1. The board has to be 10 in length and 1 in height
2. The computer puts on the board one length-one-ship and one length-two-  ship
3. The user has to repeatedly shoot in one of the 10 possible position
4. Computer will respond to every shot with "water", "hit", "sunk", "already hit"
5. When all the ships have sunk, the game ends with the computer that tells you how many shots were needed.

What I came up with until now:

1. Define a method **String buildBoard()** that returns a random string made of 7 characters "water"; 2 characters, which have to be next to each other, for the "no hit length-two-ship"; and 1 character for the "no hit length-one-ship"
2. Define a method **boolean endGame(String s)** that returns true if all the ships were sunk.
3. Define a method **String manageShot(String s, int p)** that, given a Board configuration and a shot in position p, prints out the outcome of the shot (as explained above), and returns the new Board configuration.
4. Finally, define a **void main(String[] args)** method that manages input, method calls and the final print.

Do you think it could work?
Hopefully I have explained it in an understandable way.

My problem is that I have absolutely no idea on how to generate a random String especially if I have to keep two characters next to each other. Can someone please explain me how to do it?

Can you have a look at my code and see if it's all right or if it can be simplified?

```
    public class UnidimensionalBattleship {

        /* x - miss (no ships here)
         * . - sea  (available for firing)
         * s - enemy ship (available for firing)
         * c - enemy ship (2 spaces, available for firing) */

        public static String map() {
            String sea = new String("..........");
            int pos;
            Random rnd = new Random();

            pos = rnd.nextInt(sea.length());
            sea = sea.substring(0, pos) + "s" + sea.substring(pos + 1);

            int shipsSet = 0;
            do {
                if (sea.substring(pos).equals(".") && sea.substring(pos+1).equals(".")) { //pos available
                    sea.substring(pos).equals("cc");
                    shipsSet++;
                }
            }while(shipsSet < 2);

            return sea;
        }

        public static String manageShot(String sea, int p) {
            char outcome = sea.charAt(p);
            switch(outcome) {
                case '.': System.out.println("Miss");
                    sea=sea.substring(p, p) + "x" + sea.substring(p+1);
                    break;

                case 's': System.out.println("Sunk!");
                    sea=sea.substring(p, p) + "x" + sea.substring(p+1);
                    break;

                case 'c': System.out.println("Hit!");
                    sea=sea.substring(p, p) + "x" + sea.substring(p+1);
                    break;

                case 'x': System.out.println("Already Hit");
                    break;
            }
            return sea;
        }

        public static boolean endGame(String sea) {
            int i; //counter
            i=0;

            for (i=0; i<sea.length(); i++) {
                if (sea.charAt(i)=='.'|| sea.charAt(i)=='x')
                    i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I have absolutely no idea on how to generate a random String especially if I have to keep two characters next to each other. Can someone please explain me how to do it?

Since you need to do it in String, some simple String manipulation with String functions will work. In order for you to determine whether it is a "hit", a "sunk", a "miss", or already hit, you can have a set of predefined letters to represent each of those.

**For example:**

```
x - miss (no ships here)
. - sea (available for firing)
s - enemy ship (available for firing)
c - enemy ship (2 spaces, available for firing)
```

To generate a string with ships on random positions, there are many ways to do this. You can use a StringBuilder and concatenate the String or simply use a char array and convert it to string after positioning the ships:

```
char[] sea = new char[10];
for(int x=0; x<sea.length; x++)
    sea[x] = '.';  //set everything as sea first

Random rnd = new Random();
sea[rnd.nextInt(sea.length)] = 's';  //sea ship at random position
```

If you have multiple types of ships, use a different symbol to identify them.
If you have more than one ship, use a loop to fill the sea:

```
int shipsSet = 0;
do
{
    int pos = rnd.nextInt(sea.length);
    if(sea[pos] == '.'){  //pos available
        sea[pos] = 's';
        shipsSet++;
    }
}while(shipsSet < 2);
```

**Converting char array to String:**

```
String map = String.valueOf(sea);
```

**Generating the outcome:**

```
int attackPos = scn.nextInt();

char outcome = map.charAt(attackPos);
switch(outcome){
    case '.':  System.out.println("Miss");
               //use substring to mark this spot as "X"
               break;
    case 's':  System.out.println("Sunk!");   //ship 's' only takes 1 space
               //use substring to mark this spot as "X"
               break;
    case 'c':  System.out.println("Hit!");    //ship 'c' takes 2 spaces
               //use substring to mark this spot as "X"
               break;
    case 'x':  System.out.println("Already Hit");
               break;
}
```

The above shall give you a very good idea where to start and how to implement your entire program. If you are not allowed to use char array, simply use StringBuilder. If it is also not allowed, just use substring to generate a map with ships on random positions.

Comment: Your ships may overlap, and I don't usually like loops that continue while a random criteria is not met. I could be wrong but that sounds expensive for a high number of ships, since collisions become more and more likely

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to understand how it works. If i' getting this right I have to define a Random rnd2 = new Random() for the second ship (c) too. but how I get it to take to places?

Comment: Dici, I don't need to worry about a high number of ships, I only need two

Comment: @Dici If the ships collide, it will generate a new position, so eventually there will be n ships as required. There are so many ways to do this. A more efficient way will be too much for OP. Of course we can simply generate an array like "sss......." and shuffle them, but I am providing a solution which is sufficiently good enough to solve his problem and not trying to kill a mosquito with an atomic bomb ;-P

Comment: @user3437460 Nope, because the ships have a length.  They can overlap without occupying the same start index, you don't check for that

Comment: @Dici I leave that for OP (on how to deal with ships not overlapping for different sizes), I am not going to code everything for him. Further more he is only asking for ideas, I think I already provided more than what he asked for.

Comment: @user3437460 by the way `character` is not a Java type

Comment: @Daniele No, you only create the random object once. That is, `Random rnd = new Random()` once. To use it, just `rnd.nextInt(val)`.

Comment: @user3437460 I don't know, personally I prefer deleting my answer rather than giving a broken code. Depending on how generic and how nice you want this function to be, this can actually be tricky

Comment: @user3437460 I get an error when I type character[], because it says it cannot be resolved as a type. I think I need to declare it somehow but I think it is an array and I have no idea on how to declare it.

Comment: @DanieleC nope, that was a typo. He fixed it. By the way I should tell you that this code is broken and does not handle overlaps

Comment: @DanieleC Look at my edited codes, I already changed it to `char` instead of `character`.

Comment: @user3437460 Ok, now it makes sense! Thanks!!

Comment: @DanieleC If it helps, you can consider accepting my answer ;-)

Comment: I will, but I'm still trying to figure out how it works and how use it in the right way. By the way, I need to create my map using substrings, so I thought I create a sea string and then put randomly the ships (two other strings) in it, but how can i do it? I can't use the concat method. I probably need the substring method, but I have to use it in a random way and in reverse, how do I do it? Sorry for having so many questions but I'm a beginner :)

Comment: @DanieleC You can easily achieve it by: `String sea = sea.substring(0, 4) + "S" + sea.substring(5);` for example if you want you ship to be at 4th position. `"...s......"`. To make it random, let 4 be rnd.nextInt(sea.length()). and adjust the last value accordingly.

Comment: @DanieleC For ships with 2 spaces, it is equally easy, just use a substring as above: `String sea = sea.substring(0, 4)+"CC"+sea.substring(6);`  Note that, the third portion of the string now begins with sea.substring(6) because your "C ship" takes up one more space now. Lastly, there is no need to reverse anything.

Comment: @user3437460 **sea = sea.substring(0, rnd.nextInt(sea.length())) + "s" + sea.substring(sea.indexOf("s"));** this should work right?

Comment: @DanieleC It will work only if you have 1 ship "S". since you have more than 1, you can't do that as the first ship will interfere the next ship "S" you are going to add. Just use a variable to hold the random position for the ship, then for the 3rd portion of the string: `sea.substring(pos+1); ` where pos is the random position generated for ship "S". This whole statement should be like `String sea = sea.substring(0, pos) + "S" + sea.substring(pos+1);`

Comment: no, I've got one ship "s" and one ship "cc". The problem is that there is a probability that this two ships overlap, right?

Comment: @DanieleC To prevent overlap, just use a do-while loop, keep generating a new position till ship is within bounds. To make it easy, generate the position for the larger ship first (random value from 0 to 8 so it won't go out of bounds). I think I helped too much for the implementation. I am almost doing your entire work. >.<

Comment: ok so i need to define a pos variable **pos = and.nextInt(sea.length());**

Comment: I'm really trying to understand sorry, but I'm starting to think that this assignment is way too difficult for me, since the lectures started 2 weeks ago :(

Comment: If you only have 1 big and 1 small ship, no need to use varable `pos`. Just do it like what you did (I.e using indexOf).

Comment: @user3437460 could you please have a look at my code and see if it alright?

Comment: @DanieleC `sea.substring(p, p).equals("x");` is not doing anything, you are not updating sea. Should be `sea = sea.substring....` Anyway this is not a place for code review. It is for asking specific questions and I've done much more than what I supposed to....

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got the first part with this - you can use RandomStringUtils from Apache Commons...
[https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html#random(int, java.lang.String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html#random(int,%20java.lang.String))

As you can see, it takes an integer and a String - the Integer is the length of the string and the String is the group of characters it will use.

I will have a poke around in the internet to see if I can help you with keeping the two characters together.

Comment: Thanks, what if I consider the two characters as a substring? even though I don't know how to code it exactly

Comment: Why killing a fly with a towel when you can use an atomic bomb

Comment: @Dici I didn't have any atomic bombs to hand :)

Comment: ^^ Sorry what I meant is that you don't usually expect a student to use Apache or any external library for a small project